# Road Network Accessibility

Tags: qgis, vector, network, road, analysis

I am working in QGIS with 3 layers: one is road network and other is hospitals and locations of accidents , later two layers are as points, I want to figure out what accident location (points ) are under a specific (lets say 5 mins ) of driving time from hospital locations (points ) along roads. Can anyone help me with this?

The only plugin that I found did this sort of analysis was road graph but it will give me just distance between two points but I want it to be like a buffer or range kind of output, and I can't do it manually using road graph as I have like 300 accident locations.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Service Area from layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#qgisserviceareafromlayer). Use the roads as network, the accident point layer as input `Vector layer with start points`, then set `Path type to calculate` to fastest and travel cost to the time you want to use. In the advanced Parameters, you can make more settings, e.g. if you have one way roads or information about max. speed.